# ptrace PTRACE_PEEKTEXT error

Tags: linux, system-calls, ptrace, ebpf

Why I get this error when I use ptrace PTRACE_PEEKTEXT in my C program??

the part of program that I use PTRACE_PEEKTEXT in it is:

```
static void read_file(pid_t child, char *file)
{
    char *child_addr;
    int i;

    child_addr = (char *) ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, child, sizeof(long)*RDI, 0);

    do {
        long val;
        char *p;

        val = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, child, child_addr, NULL);
        if (val == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "PTRACE_PEEKTEXT error: %s", strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
        child_addr += sizeof (long);

        p = (char *) &val;
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof (long); ++i, ++file) {
            *file = *p++;
            if (*file == '\0') break;
        }
    } while (i == sizeof (long));
}
```

(it is part of [this program](https://www.alfonsobeato.net/c/modifying-system-call-arguments-with-ptrace/))

Why does this error occur ??

```
PTRACE_PEEKTEXT error: Input/output error[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page, `EIO` means:

> is invalid, or an attempt was made to read from or
> write to an invalid area in the tracer's or the tracee's
> memory, or there was a word-alignment violation, or an
> invalid signal was specified during a restart request.

So the `child_addr` variable passed to `ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, ...)` is likely incorrect. A good start would be to check the result of `ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, ...)` for errors.

Comment: the peek_user is getting me syscall number like 1 for write, but when I try to get its arguments I get this error.

Comment: oh, I found the problem. I called ptrace for PEEK_USER twice continuously. first for syscall num and last for argument and I think it is incorrect. but how can I get the whole of the data at once??